# I have 'keep me logged in' turned on but get logged out anyway - cookies disabled but mse added as an exception.

Tags: support

I recently disabled cookies on my browser (Firefox 26 or Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m - I use both); however I have also added math.stackexchange.com (and other URLs I regularly use) as an exception so its cookies continue to be accepted by both browsers. I can log on fine, and the site works normally once logged in.

The problem is that when I restart the computer (without logging out of mse), I have to log on again the next time I turn the computer on and navigate to mse. I didn't have to do this prior to the change I made to my browsers' behavior: I would always be logged in regardless of computer restarts, unless I'd explicitly logged myself out.

I'm wondering if it is actually a problem with my Google login also related to cookies, because I use Google to logon to mse. I have added cookie exceptions for Google as well.

I'd like to continue having cookies disabled by default, but have sites such as mse that I want to use be listed as exceptions and have everything work as before for those sites. Is this possible and if so how? Do other methods of logging in (via Stackexchange etc.) work better in this regard?